# LINQ WHERE clause equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, linq

I am looking to extract information from my javascript array `lstObj' that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "DealerId": "1",
    "Type": "Apple,Orange"
  },
  {
    "DealerId": "2",
    "Type": "Mango"
  },
  {
    "DealerId": "3",
    "Type": "Mango"
  }
]
```

I want to check if there is an item that has Type = Mango and DealerID not = 2.
In C# linq I would do something like this:

```
if(lstObj.Any(x=>x.Type.Split(',').Contains("Mango") && x.DealerID != 2))
{
      //Do something
}
```

How can I achieve the same using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `some`:

```
var result= array.some(function (item) {
    return  item.Type.split(",").includes("Mango") && item.DealerID != 2;
});
```

Comment: What's the difference with filter?

Comment: Some is equivalent to Any and Filter is equivalent to Where.

Answer (score 13):

This should do. If there is no item it will return empty array, otherwise it will return items.

```
let result = lstObj.filter(dealer =>  dealer.Type.split(',').includes('Mango') && dealer.DealerId != 2);
```

```js
let lstObj = [
  {
    "DealerId": "1",
    "Type": "Apple,Orange"
  },
  {
    "DealerId": "2",
    "Type": "Mango"
  },
  {
    "DealerId": "3",
    "Type": "Mango"
  }
]

let result = lstObj.filter(dealer => dealer.Type.split(',').includes('Mango') && dealer.DealerId != 2)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I added the full code snippet so you can check it out.